# Can not figure out, how local SQL Servers are installed and get connection string to them

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I am trying to connect to a local SQL Server database (currently installed Microsoft SQL Server 2017 [as shown in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fhi9.png)) with C#. I've searched for about some SQL Server clients for C#, but in every tutorial or guide, there are always connection strings as a constant (can not figure out how to get it).

Some details:

- **Platform**: Windows 10 - x64 bit
- **SQL Manager**: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18.2
- **IDE**: Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

**In addition**: Can you guys tell me, how can I create new server? (I figured out that, creating new SQL Server on local machine is done by installing new SQL Server software or something?) I am so confused, because once, I had tried to uninstall some SQL Server softwares from the control panel, and suddenly server has disappeared. Any suggestions how can I install my own server for example? With name, that I want to call it.

Comment: The screenshot seems to indicate SQL Server **2017** - not 2012 ...

Comment: How to create a new server ? install the software remembering that sql server for any form of commercial use is not free and you shouldnt use the dev one and sqlexpress type is limited..  Secondly, the connection string is very well defined in terms of paramters it needs some minimal data.. We cannot guide you here through everything you asked its too big a an answer. Please grab a book or tutorial on basic SQL admin

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve, i.e. what do you think you need SQL Server for?